# Using an intranet server as gateway and proxy mirror for accessing a public remote

Tags: git, git-bare

*Backgroud:*

> We have an interesting question. We're trying to fetch a git repo from
>   public accessible location into our development server (server), which
>   has internet to both corporate network and public internet.
>
> Then, inside our corporate network, we have a few development boxes
>   (clients), that only have access to the development server.
>   Periodically, we want to fetch new change from
>
> public internet -> server -> clients.
>
> What we do now is git clone at server from public internet, then, git
>   clone at client from server. The problem is that if the server did not
>   track remote branch locally, the client will not be able to fetch the
>   new branch.

**Question:** Will git clone --bare in the server allow us to fetch change in the client-side without creating local tracked branches in server? What else can we do?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `git clone --mirror` on your server, and a normal `git clone` on each client.

Comment: @Patrick: man pages are your friend; the [`git clone` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) will tell you more about what `--bare` and `--mirror` do and don't do ;)